# How can i Prevent form refreshing on First form, and need refreshing on second form after submission

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, forms

I am trying to create a user web chat.
I Listed Bunch of users on the left side using while-loop and form, and submit button helps to choose the user to chat. after selection of users, user can chat with the person selected. help of second form.
my problem is the form get reset and user need to select the person again and again for each insertion.

```
  <body class="bdy">

    <div class="containe1">
      <div class="CHAT"><h4>Chat Box</h4></div>
      <div class="people-name"><p><?php
      $policeqry="SELECT registration.name,registration.reg_id,registration.role FROM registration WHERE `role`='Police'";
      $result=mysqli_query($conn,$policeqry);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<form method='post' class='form1'><input type='radio' name='policeids' value=".$row['reg_id']." id='register-id' checked hidden>
                <input type='submit'  name='submit1' style='color: white;' value=".$row['name']." id='name'  class='PoliceList'>
                </form>";
                }
}
                ?></p></div>
                      <div class="name-of-the-police"><h1>
                        <?php  if(!isset($_REQUEST['submit1'])) { 
                           $pidsa=$row['reg_id'];
                          $pnqry="SELECT registration.name,registration.reg_id,registration.role FROM registration WHERE `role`='Police';";
                          $pnget=mysqli_query($conn,$pnqry);
                          $row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($pnget);
                          
                          echo $row2['name'];?> </h1> </div> <?php
                         } else if(isset($_REQUEST['submit1'])) { 
                            $pidsa=$_REQUEST['policeids'];
                            $pnqry="SELECT registration.name,registration.reg_id,registration.role FROM registration WHERE `reg_id`='$pidsa';";
                            $pnget=mysqli_query($conn,$pnqry);
                            $row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($pnget);
                            echo $row2['name'];?> </h1> </div>
                        <div class="chat" id="chat1">
                          
                          <?php 
                          a:
                          $getmsg="SELECT * FROM `tbl_message`;";
                          $getall=mysqli_query($conn,$getmsg);
                          if($getall->num_rows>0){
                          while($row3=mysqli_fetch_array($getall)){
                              if($row3['out_regid']==$pidsa && $row3['in_regid']==$user){
                                  ?><div class='recived-text'><?php echo "<p class='aliglft'>".$row3['msg']."</p>" ?> </div>
                               <?php }
                            else if($row3['out_regid']==$user && $row3['in_regid']==$pidsa) { 
                           ?> <div class="send-text"><?php echo "<p class='aligryt'>".$row3['msg']."</p>" ?> </div><?php
                          }
                        }
                      }else{
                        echo "<div class='send-text'>No message recived yet</div>";
                      }
                    }
                   ?> 
                       <div class='ninputs'> <form class='sendtxt' method='post'>
                            <input type='text' name='msginp' class='sendTextBox' required >
                            <input type='hidden' name='policeid' value='<?php echo $pidsa ?>' id="policeReg" hidden >
                            <input type='submit' name='submit3' value='submit' class='SentTextButton'>
                          </form>
                  </div></div><?php
                          if(isset($_REQUEST['submit3'])){
                            $policeid=$_REQUEST['policeid'];
                            $usrmsg=$_REQUEST['msginp'];
                            $msginp="INSERT INTO `tbl_message` (`msg_id`, `out_regid`, `in_regid`, `msg`) VALUES (NULL, '$user', '$policeid', '$usrmsg');";
                            mysqli_query($conn,$msginp);
                          }
                          ?>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </body>
                </html>
                <script>
                var chatHistory = document.getElementById("chat1");
                chatHistory.scrollTop = chatHistory.scrollHeight;

                </script>
```

[This is The Output Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trbft.jpg)

what I want is after selecting form-1 I need the values to be same soo the user can chat further. but it keeps resetting the form soo user will have to Click on the user again to chat with the user again.